# Help understanding the solution of the Schrodinger equation in a finite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Given a [finite well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well) like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/Finite_Potential_Well_Symmetric.svg/800px-Finite_Potential_Well_Symmetric.svg.png) I found that the TISE has the general solutions. $$\psi_{1}(x)=A_{+}e^{ikx}+A_{-}e^{-ikx} \qquad x\in[-L,L] $$
$$\psi_{2}(x)=B_{+}e^{k^{'}x}+B_{-}e^{-k^{'}x} \qquad x\in(-\infty,-L)$$
$$\psi_{3}(x)=C_{+}e^{k^{'}x}+C_{-}e^{-k^{'}x} \qquad x\in(L,\infty)$$

And I realise that the wavefunction cannot be infinite meaning $B_{-}=C_{+}=0$. My textbook says that $\psi_{1}(x)\propto Cos(kx),Sin(kx)$ which would only be the case if $A_{+}/A_{-}=\pm 1$. Despite this making sense I cant seem to prove it like I did with an infinite well by matching the wavefunctions at each boundary; I just end up with a mess of simultaneous equations that I cant resolve.

Could somone show a proof that $A_{+}/A_{-}=\pm1$, I am not sure if I am lacking in information or mathematical ability.

**Answer**

Having done some more reasearch, the derivation I have seen involve constrianing the solutions to being either symetric of antisymetric. I.e. $\psi_{1}(-x)=\pm \psi_{1}(x)$, using this as opposed to matching wavefunctions you can show that:

$$A_{+}e^{-ikx}+A_{-}e^{ikx}=\pm (A_{+}e^{ikx}+A_{-}e^{-ikx})$$
$$A_{+}(e^{-ikx}\mp e^{ikx})=A_{-}(-e^{ikx}\pm e^{-ikx})$$
$$\frac{A_{+}}{A_{-}}=-\left(\frac{e^{ikx}\mp e^{-ikx}}{e^{-ikx}\mp e^{ikx}}\right)=\pm1$$

Im not sure if this is entirely correct but it makes sense to me. This said I have no idea why symetry can be constrained so If anyone could link a good source that would be very helpful as I could not find any.

Comment: Detailed solutions to this problem can be found in a multitude of elementary textbooks or on the web.

Comment: Check your boundaries on $\psi 2$. Missing a sign I think

Answer (score 1):

For your edited post:

We can impose the secondary constraint that $\psi(-x) = \pm\psi(x)$ because the Hamiltonian has an even potential. This is often left as an exercise for readers ;), so I'll leave it to you to prove it.

> For even potentials, that is, $V(x) = V(-x)$, show that if $\psi(x)$ satifies the Schrodinger equation, then $\psi(-x)$ does too.

Answer (score 0):

You can go another way in this as well.

You want some coefficients to be zero to avoid blowing up at infinity.

By the same symmetry arguments, you want $\psi_2(-x)=+-\psi_3(x)$.

Means coefficients are the same up to a sign for the decaying wave functions.

Even odd symmetry requires that the in well function be sine for off wave functions, or cosine for even.

Using all that you only have 3 coefficients per case, even or odd.

Check Eulers formula for complex exponentiation, to wrap up proof that A coefficients are equal.